# Add a new category to navigation called new arrivals

Tags: category, navigation, category-products, magento-1.9.1.1, new-products

I am trying to add a "new arrivals" category to my top navigation. Is there a simple way to add this? I have attached a photo for what I m trying to accomplish.

This is what I was thinking but I am not sure if it would work.

1. I found an extension called "Sort by Date" and I was going to install that
2. I was going to create a subcategory called "New Arrivals" and make it redirect to a CMS page that would include a product page with products from all the categories and sorted by date.

What do you think? Would this redirect negatively impact SEO?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The screenshot I displayed is from sammoon.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the new arrivals category is on the same level in the category tree as your other categories (Handbags, Jewellery etc), you can just edit the category and change the option "include in navigation menu" to "yes". This is located on the "General Information" tab of the category edit screen.

Out the box Magento builds the menu on the frontend based on this so providing your theme has continued to do that it should just appear (after probably clearing cache)

You will need to move the category up the tree if you want it to appear first in the list. I.e. it needs to be above Handbags.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Is there any way that I can make it where the new arrivals category automatically include products from all the existing categories and possibly sort the products to display the newest uploaded at the top?

This is what I was thinking but I am not sure if it would work.

1. I found an extension called "Sort by Date" and I was going to install that

2. I was going to create a subcategory called "New Arrivals" and make it redirect to a CMS page that would include a product page with products from all the categories and sorted by date.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it actually isn't as easy as it may seem. If you are not familiar with code, I won't go into too many details. If you are, you will need to create a category, and then assign a custom layer.

Your custom layer would extend the core one, but would filter products from the root category instead of the current category, and you can then easily add an additional filter for the "New" status.

That is the only *clean* solution that would make the layered navigation work, and would avoid you going through a lot of "hacks".